# Calling jQuery Dialog twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have 2 functions: `myFunc1` and `myFunc2`. When `myFunc1` is called, a [jQuery confirmation Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation) appears. When the user clicks yes, `myFunc2` is called, which should show another dialog.
But, despite successfully calling `myFunc2`, the second dialog never appears.

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xn05swrL/2/).

```
function myFunc1() {
  dialog().then(function(data) {
    if (data == "yes") {
      console.log("clicked yes: show another dialog")
      myFunc2();
    } else {
      console.log("clicked no")
    }
  });
}

function myFunc2() {
  dialog();
  console.log("myFunc2 is called")
}

function dialog(title) {
  var def = $.Deferred();
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      "Yes": function() {
        def.resolve("yes");
        $(this).dialog("close");
      },
      "No": function() {
        def.resolve("no");
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }
  });
  return def.promise();
}

$("button").on("click", myFunc1);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are resolving the Deffered-Object before you are actually closing the first dialog. So when the `then()`-callback is hit, the dialog is still open, therefore no new one is created.

Just swap the functions and it should be working.

```
"Yes": function() {
    $(this).dialog("close");
    def.resolve("yes");           
},
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/37r7Lsk8/1/)

> When the Deferred is resolved, any doneCallbacks added by deferred.then() or deferred.done() are called. Callbacks are executed in the order they were added

[.resolve()](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolve/)

Answer (score 0):

You're using the same div to create all your dialogs, if you need to have more than one dialog open at once that will be an issue.

```
// Get a random unique number to use as the dialog id
var guid = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999999999999) + 1;
// Clone the dialog div and give it a new name
$("#dialog").clone()[0].id = guid;
// Create the dialog with the new unique div
$("#"+guid).dialog({...});
```

Also,

```
// Make sure you remove the div after you close it
$(this).dialog("close").remove();
```